# cakephp running a Shell

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm new to cakephp and I'm trying to run a Shell

my command is:

```
bin/cake CreateUsers
```

this file can be found in:

```
myproject/src/Shell/CreateUsersShell.php
```

but how could I run another shell from another directory?

Say for example, in

```
myproject/src/Shell/Admin/AdminBatchShell
```

I tried the command,

```
bin/cake Admin/AdminBatch
```

but I think the command fails and it cannot be found.

What could be the syntax for running shells in cakephp with directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that.

When CakePHP is looking for shells it only scans the `App\Shell` folder but not the sub-folders.

So all your shells need to be in the `App\Shell` folder.

I guess you could write a simple wrapper for your admin shell that looks like

```php
namespace App\Shell;

class AdminBatchShell extends \App\Shell\Admin\AdminBatchShell {

}
```

Which basically creates a copy of your admin shell in the proper namespace so you can use this command

`bin/cake admin_batch`

#### Notes

Unlike the web access that is public and prefixes make sense because you want the admin stuff to be secured, in case of shells prefixing them does not make much sense because they can only be executed from your hosting command environment so only web administrators or cron jobs can run it.